# bug noticed rendering positions with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code which first creates a variable positions with all x,y positions of an image from it's width and height. Then with select area(s) in an image remove these positions from a clone of positions to have the the sum of all positions in two different arrays.

```
var positions = [];
var areas = {}
var area_counter = 0;

var image_width = $('.img-class')[0].naturalWidth;
var image_height = $('.img-class')[0].naturalHeight;

var area = image_width * image_height;

var img_width = 0;
var img_height = 0;
for (counter = 0; counter < area; counter++) { 
    positions.push([img_width, img_height]);

    img_width += 1;
    if (img_width == image_width) {
        img_width = 0;
        img_height += 1;
    }
}

var drop_boxes = $('.drop-box');
var area_grid = [];
var image_width = $('.img-class')[0].naturalWidth;
var image_height = $('.img-class')[0].naturalHeight;

drop_boxes.each(function() {
    var position = $(this).position();
    var width =  $(this).width();
    var height = $(this).height();
    var positions_clone = positions.slice(0);
    //console.log(positions_clone.length);

    var top_offset = parseInt((position['top'] * image_width)/img_width);
    var left_offset = parseInt((position['left'] * image_height)/img_height);

    position['top'] = top_offset;
    position['left'] = left_offset;

    var width_offset = parseInt((width * image_width)/img_width);
    var height_offset = parseInt((height * image_height)/img_height);

    var width_counter = 1;
    var height_counter = 1;

    var area = width_offset * height_offset;                

    if (position['top'] < image_height-1 && position['left'] < image_width) {
        for (counter = 0; counter < area; counter++) {       
            var pos = [position['left']+width_counter, position['top']+height_counter];

            var index = positions.findIndex(function(item) {
              // return result of comparing `data` with `item`

              // This simple implementation assumes that all `item`s will be Arrays.
              return pos.length === item.length &&
                     item.every(function(n, i) { return n === pos[i] });
            });

            if (index > -1) {
                positions_clone.splice(index, 1);
            }

            area_grid.push(pos);

            width_counter += 1;

            if (width_counter == width_offset) {
                width_counter = 1;
                height_counter += 1;
            }

            if (counter%100 == 0) {
                var percentage = Math.round((counter/area)*100, 2);
                console.log("Percentage: "+percentage+"%");
            }
        }
        console.log(positions_clone.length);
        console.log(area_grid.length);

        areas[area_counter] = {'area': area_grid, 'positions': positions_clone};
        parent.find('.area').text(area_counter);
        area_counter += 1;
    }               


});
```

problem is when I now use these positions to render an image there's either offsetted position or missing positions. As seen in these images.
[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDbub.jpg)
[first example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRHdj.jpg)

Comment: What is `if (img_width == image_width)` for? It evaluates `true` every iteration of the loop.

Comment: there's two counters; for width and height if they're equal then it adds one to height resets img_width = 0 and start's a new row

Comment: Oh my bad, I didn't realize those were different variables.  Silly brain.

Comment: Do you mean to be using the `img_width` and `img_height` variables to calculate `top_offset` and `left_offset`?  Without a working example or knowledge of what the HTML and `drop-box` class are supposed to be, I can't be guessing.  It seems like *debugging* would be the easiest solution to finding this bug.

Comment: I created the positions using var img_width = $('.img-class').width();
        var img_height = $('.img-class').height()

Comment: let me show you a screen record of this

Comment: Making a snippit would be better!